# Using CakePHP 1.3 but have no database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What's a good why to use CakePHP 1.3 for my website, but I have no database, since the site is pretty static?

Comment: better yet: don't use framework at all if your site is pretty much static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple HTML to develop a site which is having all Static Content. And if it having a single contct page or something which you can develop in simple PHP. You don't need to use CakePHP for that.

CakePHP framework is used for web application that needs to interact more with databases.

Comment: yes and no, as it has features for components and structure to be used even if you don't need a model

Comment: You have mentioned you website will have more static pages. If that case you don't need CakePHP framework. If you have more static pages and will be using more common html like headers and footers you can use simple php to do that. No need of CakePHP framework.

Comment: true but there's headers, footers, url rewriting, elements, etc.

Comment: what's used in php to do rerouting?

Comment: yeah i'll just do it straight php and use includes for elements and the rest of the stuff

Answer (score 2):

Although I generally agree with gvLearner's point if you'd like to have a static html site, but still use some of CakePHP's abilities and be able to easily transform the site to a dynamic one in the future you can use Cake's built in [Pages Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/958/The-Pages-Controller).

The CakePHP core ships with a default controller called the Pages Controller that is generally used to serve static pages. Check out the documentation link I sent, I hope it'd would do you good.

Cheers, 
   Borislav.